# Query that returns a list of people born in Paris from DBpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I cant figure out how to syntax a query that gets all the people who born in Paris

The results I want to get are:

```
dbpedia:Sergi_Pàmies
dbpedia:Princess_Eugénie_of_Greece_and_Denmark
dbpedia:Laurent_Fabius
dbpedia:Auguste_Rodin
dbpedia:Manu_Chao
dbpedia:Louis_Antoine_de_Bougainville
dbpedia:Maria_Francisca_of_Savoy
dbpedia:Alexandre_Coste
dbpedia:Jean_le_Rond_d'Alembert
        etc......
```

The resource page is: http://dbpedia.org/page/Paris

Comment: Sorry if my question is badly structured. I rephrase it and I believe that is better now. @Lukas Please dont judge ppl that u don't know!

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer for my problem. The query bellow get everyone who born in Paris.

```
PREFIX dbponto: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT ?person 
WHERE { ?person dbpedia-owl:birthPlace dbpedia:Paris }
```

Sorry if my question above is not well structured but I am a beginner in programming.